# How to use typeof for conditional assigment to object value in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have object, where some values are strings and some numbers.

I want to trim all values which are strings.

```
type OptionalParams = {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: number;
};
const optionalParams: OptionalParams = {};

const keys = Object.keys(optionalParams) as Array<keyof OptionalParams>;

keys.forEach((key: keyof OptionalParams) => {
  const paramValue = optionalParams[key];
  if (typeof paramValue === 'string') {
    const newValue = (paramValue as string).trim();
    optionalParams[key] = newValue as keyof OptionalParams;
  }
});
```

But I get ts-error:

> Type '"a" | "b" | "c"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
>
> Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. ts(2322)

I don't get it if I remove 'c' property, but I need it. I add if with typeof, but typescript doesn't understand it.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but if you convert key to string it works ok

```
type OptionalParams = {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: number;
}
const optionalParams: OptionalParams = {
  a: 'some ',
  c: 1
}

const keys = Object.keys(optionalParams) as Array<keyof OptionalParams>

keys.forEach((key) => {
  const paramValue = optionalParams[key]
  if (typeof paramValue === 'string') {
    const newValue = paramValue.trim()
    optionalParams[key as string] = newValue
    optionalParams[key as 'a' | 'b'] = newValue
  }
})

console.log('optionalParams', optionalParams)
```

Result

```
❯ ts-node demo.ts
optionalParams { a: 'some', c: 1 }
```

Tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a different configuration file tsconfig.json, because I have error with your solution: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'OptionalParams'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'OptionalParams'.ts(7053)

Comment: I would suggest trying to *narrow* `key` to `"a" | "b"` instead of *widening* it to `string`.  There might be ways of doing this without type assertions, but if you're using an assertion that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `key` is of type `keyof OptionalParams`, and the only value you can safely write to `OptionalParams[keyof OptionalParams]` is `undefined`.  (You can safely *read* `string | number | undefined`).  The compiler doesn't understand that your `typeof` check has any implications on the type of `key`, so all it sees is that you're writing a `string` to a variable that can only safely take `undefined`, and it complains.

The enforcement of safe writes to indexed access properties did not happen in TS3.4 and below.  This behavior is due to a [change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) that was [released with TypeScript 3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).

The way to fix this is to convince the compiler that `key` is in the subset of `keyof OptionalParams` that lets you write `string` values to it.  Here's one way to make the compiler figure out which keys are suitable for writing particular types of values:

```
type KeysForWriting<T extends object, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: [V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type KW = KeysForWriting<OptionalParams, string>; // "a" | "b"
```

One way to proceed here is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to inform the compiler that, after the `typeof` check, you know for sure that `key` is of type `KeysForWriting<OptionalParams, string>`:

```
keys.forEach(key => {
  const paramValue = optionalParams[key];
  if (typeof paramValue === "string") {
    const newValue = paramValue.trim();
    optionalParams[key as KeysForWriting<OptionalParams, string>] = newValue;
  }
});
```

That works without error.

---

Another thing you could do is abstract your code into a more [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) property-modification function, which takes advantage of the [unsafe but still-intentional behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) whereby you are allowed to write a value of type `T[K]` to a variable of type `T[K]`, even when `K` might be a union of keys (which is one of the ways it could be unsafe).  Like this:

```
function modifyProp<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
  t: T,
  k: K,
  check: (x: T[K]) => x is V,
  cb: (x: V) => T[K]
) {
  const orig = t[k];
  if (check(orig)) {
    t[k] = cb(orig);
  }
}
```

Here `modifyProp(t, k, check, cb)` takes an object `t`, a key `k`, a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) `check`, and a callback `cb`.  The implementation checks to see if `t[k]` passes the type guard `check`, and if so, modifies its value via the callback.  In your case, the check you want to do is "is this a `string`":

```
function isString(x: any): x is string {
  return typeof x === "string";
}
```

And then your call becomes the one-liner:

```
keys.forEach(key => {
  modifyProp(optionalParams, key, isString, x => x.trim());
});
```

---

Okay, hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwApoE5oFsBnKAXigG8AoKKNAfgC4ojhcEUBzAbhqgCMmLNhx58AxkJQBXAvwi5eAX17jUrKEnjJ02PISLM4iVJhz5iZSiqpU1KDQGsIIEuRj8AVhHHAAdM6uABRaJrrmBgCUdCQAgrj4IAA8gUgAZrDapnoWRAB8vFSBRH5pSLgAomjiABZBgWR5lBLqwFBg+gQAapjS0OShOmadRADagQC6vLQIGUGgkOntnT0YfWSk5ABErOxcW9HUtLT2GigQAO6r6+QdFtcQfiIEQZHTx4PZEcTjLhNW5yuvQg3CgAHowVAFLhylAOFAACoAZQAzH4AKwAaigABN1sAkFA+LQIVAasBgGBDBDOAhgDVpPw-GoCGCALIIcQwojpYBghHgCBIrkIeBgi4IRwIMEAIVwEDQUq4AFoAMI1NBcCBEADEaQQAA9tcqCcrpA4kOaccqLuxgMbTRwcRAjdbquJtUQTYKiHwlFQlG9bBDIQiAJpYCpQWJIpEVABKCIAkjAAHJQABiSYAGrYFtAANIuIgZ8oAdTtoiSCKhBvtKBxJCQXh8wAANFAuk1yEcoKMC3CUFBUhkERNlUJRl1-i7642+wj+xN-vQoAPmOcAG4KAO-EBLMeFfNrstWIuuUu4Ct0qvGIY5Awd3aiArgyFbNBbKAAHygW34Wy2MUpTlFUtT1C4jTNCcrTLPcwJWJ84QjHuUx8LMUDzIKSx3IQDwbNsz77IcxJQKcbSAvhtwrMCTzsC8QbHJoWTIbke4xGuxaXteiBcEkd5fCMT4iFweT-OQlHAu8-qBoUVCkgA4hUqYJkmqqZgAqqmqrJmmmY5rYaTmr4OhQAQSA4rMIBYDCYDVh2A6zhADYkCOiIdl0tZziQi4FhMeRBHwwDMAibZ8I4zAFmFJw1D4EWYQaIVLtEpBNAacIkF00VkfwzBBIlnYpU0vkTFQJEwQ4bTlAgnBWMA4xoTMcy1HFITsJwkTlcc9WOOJOVtTVjFQDJhnGWEGVIiJnD5cwmogJEzDpQgJBEbVvbysA0i4EO+ZLOlmyEVNWzKEBxYgZU1R1A0qXQWZFlWTZWghCxwy5B2gQdstk17JwHb7WldEIAxQayVQQA)